# couldn't find file 'local-time' with type 'application/javascript'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, localtime

I'm using `gem 'local_time'`

by adding `//= require local-time` in `application.js` gives error following :-

> couldn't find file 'local-time' with type 'application/javascript'

I'm following this  [local_time gem doc](https://github.com/basecamp/local_time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here i'm giving the answer as i figure out
it should be `//= require local_time` instead of `//= require local-time` which i thing written wrong in git doc of this gem.